# logger.disabled check much later in python logging module. What's the rationale?

Tags: python, logging

I am going through the code of python logging module both in Python2(2.7.12 default on Ubuntu 16.04) and Pyton 3.5 (3.5.2 default on Ubuntu 16.04).

The question is - if we look at the implementation of `def _log` that eventually calls `self.handle`, the check about `self.disabled` is done actually made in the `handle` method, but it's not done in the `_log` method.

Agree, checking it again in `self.handle` might make sense, but why not check it first thing in `self._log` or even better in `self.isEnabledFor` that avoids doing a lot of work that is done in `self._log` method.

What is it that I am missing?

**Update**: Did some profiling when logger is disabled - The code is [in the following gist](https://gist.github.com/gabhijit/3b671f10c1f6b96b0188513391faff7c#file-disabled_logger-py).

Following gists have the actual cprofile data indicating performance impact when the [logger is disabled](https://gist.github.com/gabhijit/3952327dd54582cc808bf8620a97734b) and when the [logger is enabled](https://gist.github.com/gabhijit/c93bf6b8ce95e00227ab881638792c45).

It appears, there's considerable performance impact when the logger is disabled.

May be it is worth considering?

Comment: Have you measured the performance impact? What does it amount to?

Comment: No, I have not. Will do that and update, likely it is not much, but can we not move the check upwards?

Comment: updated with performance measurements, in deed there is a considerable penalty in the case of disabled logger. When the logger is enabled, the penalty by having  the check moved ti isEnabledFor is negligible. Please take a look and let me know if there is something I am missing.

Comment: I will investigate further. Thanks.

Comment: I have raised a Python issue to track this: https://bugs.python.org/issue33606

Comment: Ok cool. I will add that as an answer for now and mark this question as answered, just to avoid keeping it unanswered.

Comment: A fix has been added which will be in Python 3.8. Thanks, Abhijit! See https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/6e3ca645e71dd021fead5a70dc06d9b663612e3a

Comment: Great! thanks for the update! Updating the link above as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indeed was an issue and is fixed now -

https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/6e3ca645e71dd021fead5a70dc06d9b663612e3a